# Is there a Ruby/Rails clause for grouping by an attribute and finding groups with two different attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouping, arel

I have many `Sandwich` 's

I am looking to group them by a `:user_id`

By which that `user_id` group has at least one Sandwich with `jelly` and one with `peanut butter`

My best attempt is :

```
Sandwich.group(:user_id).having('topping = ? AND topping = ?', "jelly", "peanut butter")
```

But I think that syntax is geared more towards counting.

These would be matches I would want..

```
[
  [user_id: "X123", topping: "peanut_butter"],
  [user_id: "X123", topping: "jelly"]
],
[
  [user_id: "Y444", topping: "peanut_butter"],
  [user_id: "Y444", topping: "jelly"],
  [user_id: "Y444", topping: "jelly"]
]
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking. Could you share your full data-model and the SQL you want to achieve? Can you have a sandwich with both jelly and peanut butter? Would that count?

Comment: Hey @rewritten so sorry about my dumb format. To answer your question, it can only be one thing. So I'm looking for both items that are linked by a single `user_id`. Note.. there can be _more than one of each_, but I only need ones where by at least one of each can be found with the same User ID. hopefully that helps..

Comment: Have you tried using `group_by`? https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by

Comment: @JoãoFernandes The idea is to delegate grouping to the database. If you use Enumerable methods, you end up loading all your data in ruby memory space (which is slower) only to discard most of it once the grouping is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in SQL using an inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sandwiches.user_id
FROM sandwiches
INNER JOIN sandwiches sandwiches_alias
  ON sandwiches.user_id = sandwiches_alias.user_id
WHERE sandwiches.topping = "jelly"
  AND sandwiches_alias.topping = "peanut butter";
```

This will return just the relevant user_ids.

With this data, you can make your grouping query much simpler:

```rb
user_ids = Sandwich.connection.execute(the_above_sql).flatten
Sandwich.where(user_id: user_ids).group(:user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @rewritten . I kinda felt there wasn't a built in rails way to do this